# Github GraphQL API, hardcoding the access token works, trying to obfuscate it does not

Tags: github, graphql, create-react-app, apollo, github-api

Below is my apollo client set up and when I hardcode the access token created on GitHub and try to ping the endpoint, it works fine, I get data back, I can play around with it etc. I tried replacing the hardcoded value into an environment variable but then I start getting a 401 unauthorized error from github.. I logged the environment variable and I got the exact string that I was hardcoding with. I don't really understand why. Could anyone help me out?

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
});
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // const token = process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB;

    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            // authorization: token ? token : null
            authorization: `bearer fullAccessTokenString`
        }
    }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an environment variable, it will just be replaced by Webpack at build time with the actual value. There is no way you can include a value in your frontend code and prevent it from being read by others.

Instead of including the access token directly inside your code, you need to implement some kind of authentication flow (like a "Log in with GitHub" button) that will allow your user to get their own access token when using your app. This is not only more secure but it also means A) you don't have to redeploy your app if the access token expires or is revoked, and B) you'll be less likely to hit the API's rate limit since every user will be using their own quota.